# Binding a C++ library using pybind11 - ImportError

Tags: python, c++, binding, importerror, pybind11

Im trying to bind a c++ library using pybind11.
the compilation works well, but I had an error when I tried to import the .so file in a python file:

```
from project_pybind11 import *
```

I have this error :

```
from project_pybind11 import *
ImportError: generic_type: type "class_derived" referenced unknown base 
type "NAMESPACE::class_derived"
```

Do you have any idea about the origin of this error ? or how I can get more details or information about this error.

I bind my class on this way :

```
  PYBIND11_MODULE(project_pbind11,m) {
    py::class_<Pyclass_derived, NAMESPACE::class_derived, NAMESPACE::class_base>(m, "class_derived")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def(py::init<const NAMESPACE::S_UINT32>(), py::arg("classnameId"))
    .def("method1", &Pyclass_derived::method1);
    .....;
  }
```

my class .cpp is :

```
namespace NAMESPACE
{

   class class_derived: public class_base

   {

    public:

    class_derived(); 
    class_derived(const NAMESPACE::S_UINT32 classderivedId);
    virtual void method1();
    ...
  };
}
```

Pyclass_derived is a class that I implemented to take into account the virtual methods.

```
 class Pyclass_derived: public NAMESPACE::class_derived{
    public:
      using NAMESPACE::class_derived::class_derived;
      void method1() override { PYBIND11_OVERRIDE(void,  
            NAMESPACE::class_derived, method1); }
     };
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error by wrapping C++ abstract class with pybind11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62854830/error-by-wrapping-c-abstract-class-with-pybind11)

Comment: Hi @wohlstad, no it is not exactly the same case. 
I bind my class on this way :
 py::class_<PyClassdervied, NAMESPACE::class_derived, NAMESPACE::class_base>(m, "class_derived")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def(py::init<const NAMESPACE::S_UINT32>(), py::arg("classnameId"))
        .....
;

my class .cpp is :

namespace NAMESPACE
 {
 class class_derived: public class_base
 {
 public:

     class_derived(); 
     class_derived(const NAMESPACE::S_UINT32 classderivedId);
};
}

Comment: I am not an expert in this area, but the answer in that post mentioned that you also have to "wrap" the base class (in addition to the derived). Did you try that ?

Comment: I tried it but I still have the same problem. in fact in my case 
the unknown base type is between the class (derived class) and the NAMESPACE::derived_class

ImportError: generic_type: type "class" referenced unknown base type "NAMESPACE::class"

Comment: I removed my "duplicate" vote. Sorry I cannot help further.

Comment: Thank you @wohlstad!
 I hope someone else helps me! :(

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Also note that `derived_class` comes from nowhere in a piece of code that is built around `class_derived`.

Comment: Hi @n.m.couldbeanAI, It was class_derived and not derived_class, I changed it above. 
I think I added the most important things in the binding. It can be a problem related to the compilation and linking ? I dont think so.

Comment: No, "most important things" don't cut it. If I cannot reproduce it, I cannot help you.

Comment: In fact, I cannot upload the c++ library here. I tried to binding of the classes of this library. what kind of details do you need ? sorry.

Comment: What kind of minimal reproducible example Can I give if in this case ?

Comment: I resolved the problem by adding :

    py::class_<class_base>(m, "class_base");
    py::class_<class_derived>(m, "NAMESPACE::class_derived");
    py::class_<Pyclass_derived, class_derived, class_base>(m, "class_derived")